# How to detect if a table view cell is tapped in xcode 7

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode7, uitableview

How do I detect if a table view cell is tapped. The guides and tutorial on the web follow the approach of adding a button to the table cell view - prototype cell. This button remains same for all rows and when tapped, returns the index of the row or cell.

I want to do this without the button. How can I invoke

```
@IBAction
```

when a cell is tapped and then perform a segue inside the function.

How should I go about it?

I added the following code, but this does not print anything

```
class MoreViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let moreOption = [
    ("My Profile"),
    ("Settings"),
    ("Logout")
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: (48/255.0), green: (187/255.0), blue: (197/255.0), alpha: 1.0);
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor .whiteColor();
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false;
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor .whiteColor()]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func logout() {
    print("Logout tapped");
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return moreOption.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let (celloption) = moreOption[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel!.text = celloption;
    cell.textLabel!.textColor =  UIColor(red: (74/255.0), green: (74/255.0), blue: (74/255.0), alpha: 1.0);
    return cell;
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    print(cell);
}
```

}

Comment: you just need to use didSelectRow UITableViewDelegate method.

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you using UITableViewDelegate method?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

In this method you will get the indexPath of cell tapped and here itself you can open the new controller if you want.

Comment: I am using the following code inside didSelectRowAt   - let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        print(cell);  - but this is not printing anything

Comment: Is this method called? Have you set tableView dataSource and delegate? cellForRowAtIndexPath is used to create the cell. Use didSelectRowAtIndexPath to get the cell tap event.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
            print(selectedItem)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the code you are not adding the tableview outlet (or variable if you are building it from code). 
You need first to add the tableview outlet to your class and then set the apropiate delegate and datasource for it

for example

```
//this is connected to your storyboard 
//It may have typing errors it is not tested 
//at this on the top of your class
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView! 

//at this on viewdidLoad or viewDidAppear 
table.delegate = self
table.datasource = self
```